# Jquery mobile panel with google maps as content does not hide content

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I have this problem, which had been working in previous versions, and I dont know what happend since its not working now.

The problem is that only the header and footer in jqm is "sliding/showing".

I've included the problem visually:

[image: Before panel]

[image: After panel]

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>AP</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

<link href="js/jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    html {height:100%}
    body {height:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
    #googleMap {height:100%}
</style>
</head>
<body id="body">
<!-- LOGIN -->
<div data-role="page" id="loginPage" data-theme="a">
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h3>AP</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- CONTENT -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="check-user" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">
            <fieldset>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password" />
                </div>
                <input type="button" data-theme="b" name="submit" id="loginSubmit"    value="Log ind">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>Version KICK-ASS</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- MAP -->
<div data-role="page" id="mapPage">
    <!-- PANEL LEFT -->
    <div data-role="panel" id="mapPanel">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="mapPanelList"></ul>
    </div>
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" id="mapHeader">
        <a href="#mapPanel">Menu</a>
        <h3 id="headerTitle"></h3>
        <a id="logout" data-icon="delete">Exit</a>
    </div>
    <!-- CONTENT -->
    <div data-role="content" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" id="mapContent">
        <div id="map" class="ui-panel-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>Version KICK-ASS</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/googlemaps3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jqm/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js">        </script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="georescue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Same code works without googlemaps..
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you assigning the class ui-panel-wrapper to the DIV id="map"? That class sets position relative and raises the zIndex. Try removing the class and see if that helps...

Comment: You made my day! Must be from an demo it came from...